# How to put the the non-active language as part of a menu in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, language-switching

How can I put the non-active language as part of a Drupal menu ? like the following : 
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always user any text as the "name" of the menu item as long as the destination is valid.
You will need to change database to allow UTF-8 strings and use proper unicodes in the computer that you use to enter text. Every user of the site must have this unicode as well. (For an example, older computers does not have Sinhalese language. So they can't view pages written using a newer computer).

Comment: I know .... I was just acting how to put the language switcher block as part of a menu in Drupal ? And only to show the non-active language .....

Answer (score 0):

You can just click the add link in whichever menu you would like to place the links in, put in the name of the language as the menu link title and the url to your translated version of the website as the path.

This is what Ayesh K was referring to.